# Is there a filter in telethon to remove bots when doing iter_messages(channel)?

Tags: telethon

`for message in client.iter_messages(channel):`

could not find any filter in telethon documentation for removing bot messages when scanning a channel,also could not see any data in messages reveling it is a bot or user.

Tried finding a filter in telethon documentation and in message data

Comment: There is no such filter (currently, anyway). However it's simple to filter them out manually (as demonstrated by the answers).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```py
async for message in client.iter_messages(channel):
    if not message.sender.bot:
        print(message.sender)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).